# Python ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Hi guys I am geting all the time an error that freaks me out cause I have allready had a similar code where it doesnt make any Problems. I guess it is because the ast.literal_eval but in my other code for a Geolocation it works fine, the only difference here is that i have 8 coordinats instead of 2 in my working code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from shapely.wkt import loads as load_wkt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import re
import ast
import io

with io.open('sample_test1.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f, io.open('sample_test2.txt.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as g:
        for line in f:
                j = re.sub(r'.*(\[.*\]).*', r'\1', line.rstrip())
                k = ast.literal_eval(j)
                p = Polygon(k)
                c = p.centroid
                print (c, file = g)
f.close()
g.close()
```

The data that the re.sub catches look like this:

```
[(38.78866,-75.56358),(41.357426,-75.56358),(41.357426,-73.88506),(38.78866,-73.88506)]
```

Here the original input:

```
703971723738288128,[(39.87181,-75.28028),(40.13792,-75.28028),(40.13792,-74.95571),(39.87181,-74.95571)],,,lmao maybe but I probably listened to TLOP almost everyday so I heard everyone song at least 10 times ðŸ˜­
703971724577148928,[(37.88661,-79.48765),(39.72362,-79.48765),(39.72362,-74.98628),(37.88661,-74.98628)],,,Whose trying to come out and enjoy this beautiful weather?
703971724635852800,[(39.87181,-75.28028),(40.13792,-75.28028),(40.13792,-74.95571),(39.87181,-74.95571)],21886583,WorkFromHomeQ102Meet5H,I just got home from work now I'm listening to #WorkFromHome ðŸ˜œ #Q102Meet5H @Q102Philly
```

I keep geting all the time this error:

```
File "polygon_csv.py", line 30, in <module>
    k = ast.literal_eval(j)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 55, in _convert
    return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000203D2EA0F98>
```

Comment: Verify the original input, this code works for me:
`import ast;
import re;
a = '[(38.78866,-75.56358),(41.357426,-75.56358),(41.357426,-73.88506),(38.78866,-73.88506)]';
j = re.sub(r'.*(\[.*\]).*', r'\1', a.rstrip());
ast.literal_eval(j)`;

Comment: I allready did that. When I do it without the ast.literal_eval(j) it works fine but the Polygon can't use the Data so i need the ast.literal_eval(j), but when I put im in it comes to the error.

Comment: Can you show the actual file input?

Comment: I edited the post now you can see the first 3 Lines of the text.